# Total power measurement in 3-phase unbalanced delta system

Tags: three-phase, delta, power-measurement, unbalanced

I have a 3-phase system with an **unbalanced** delta load, as seen in the figure below.

I want to measure the total apparent and active power consumption and if possible, the respective power consumption for each of the phases, but I am a bit confused.

I am using a 3-phase equipment from National Instruments which shows that Vc = 380V, Vb = 380V and Vc = 0V. I assume that because of the absent neutral, it uses phase A as a reference, thus Vc = Vca, Vb = Vba.

I am also measuring all three line currents.

What is the total apparent power equation? I am aware of [Blondel's Theorem](http://www.tek.com/dl/55W_28943_0_HR_Letter.pdf), but it is valid only when measuring instant power right?

Also, is it possible to measure the power of each separate phase?

[image]

Comment: You cannot measure power without a wattmeter. End of story.

Comment: You can do it without a wattmeter, it just takes more steps to do it (voltage, current, \$\cos\phi\$, harmonics, ...), that's why a wattmeter exists, to spare you the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

- The 3 Power meter method uses the meter impedance to create a virtual Y neutral node with 3 V readings
- Thus 3 meter method can measure the P in each phase and total.
- Using scalar VA products in each phase can get any result you need (VAR, PF)
- the total apparent power (scalar product) can also be measured using true Vrms* true Irms
- the reactive power can be computed by vector geometry.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am aware of all these, but I have access only to the setup I described in the question. This means 1) I cannot connect any wattmeters as per figure 14 and 2) only RMS values can be measured. If I estimate though each line-to-neutral voltage as 220V, can I multiply this with the measured currents to get each line power? Would that be correct?

Comment: you can only get apparent power without a wattmeter.